# How to parse a string with regex?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

How to retrive `DELETE` string from `ROLE_DELETE_USER` with reqular expression?

```
String role = "ROLE_DELETE_USER";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("???");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(role);
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are meant to handle patterns. You don't have much of a pattern (just one example), but this will work in at least that one case.

```
String role = "ROLE_DELETE_USER";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^ROLE_(.*)_USER$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(role);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Here, `(.*)` is a capture group. `match.group(1)` retrieves the content of the first capture group.

---

Of course, you could also just do

```
String role = "ROLE_DELETE_USER";
role = role.substring(5, role.length() - 5)
System.out.println(role);
```

Comment: When I'm trying to run your code i've got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`.

Comment: Very well! But it works not properly when I'm typing something like that `ROLE_DE__LETE_USER` (wrong expression).

Comment: @Flavio, your question does not say what *should* happen in such a case. You've given exactly one example. If it should work in other cases, you may want to specify that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
String delete = role.substring(role.indexOf("_") + 1, role.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

Comment: @Flavio, use regex only as a last resort. Reimeus' solution is far better than a regular expression for your particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't help to have only one example of strings to parse, because you could do it in multiple ways. If you wanted to, here are a couple patterns:

```
[A-Z]+_(.*)_[A-Z]+
[A-Za-z]+_(.*)_[A-Za-z]+
```

Which would come out as:

```
String role = "ROLE_DELETE_USER";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+_(.*)_[A-Z]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(role);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

An alternative solution (not using regex) would to break down the roles into a string array:

```
String input = "ROLE_DELETE_USER";
String[] tasks = input.split("_");
//args[0] == "ROLE"
//args[1] == "DELETE"
//args[2] == "USER"
```

This allows a lot more flexibility imo for figuring out what you want to do with the input.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Comment: @Flavio You need to invoke `find` or `matches` on Matcher object.

Comment: You haven't invoked any search on the matcher yet